# set compile target to resolve "new api class cannot be resolved"

Tags: android, maven, android-manifest, android-5.0-lollipop, android-maven-plugin

I want to use [MediaProjectionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html) which is added in API level 21, so I added the following code in my **AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

In my Java code I have:

```
MediaProjectionManager mpm = (MediaProjectionManager)
                                                context.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
```

But I get "`MediaProjectionManager cannot be resolved`" in Eclipse, my maven build also says "`cannot find symbol MediaProjectionManager`"

Why? How to resolve it? (I am using [android-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/))

Answer (score 0):

you have change your app to use `SDK 21` to compile the app. So that the build system is "aware" of the new methods.

if you don't have the SDK 21, you open the Android SDK Manager and download it.

Comment: I have SDK 21 installed. I thought declare targetSdkVersion="21" in AndroidManifest.xml would be enough. How to change that on Eclipse & maven pom.xml (I am using Maven-Android-Plugin)?

Comment: on manifest you're just declaring to the device that will execute the app, that this app was targeting it. I never worked with maven before (only ant and gradle) but it should be there in the pom a "targetSdk" or similar parameter

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a dependency to the library that supplies the MediaProjectionManager class.

And in Eclipse you have to use M2e and M2e-Android for the classpath to be configured correctly.